# Subtype polymorphism in scala

Tags: scala, subtype

What is the difference between following two declarations of sum functions?

```
 def sum[A](xs:List[A]) = .....

 def sum[A <: List[A]](xs:A) = ....
```

**EDIT:**
To elaborate more....

Lets say I want to write a method head on List.

I can write head as follow:

```
 def head[A](xs:List[A]) = xs(0)
```

or else we can write

```
 def head[A <: List[A]] (xs:A) = xs(0)
```

Which one to prefer and when?

*Note: one difference I figured out that implicit conversions are not applied for second one*

Comment: Try calling the second one.

Answer (score 4):

The first one takes a `List[A]` as parameter, the second one some `A` that is a subtype of `List[A]`. Consider the following example:

```
scala> trait Foo[A <: Foo[A]]
defined trait Foo

scala> class Bar extends Foo[Bar]
defined class Bar
```

The recursive type parameter on `Foo` can be useful, when you want to define a method in the trait that takes or returns the type of the subclass:

```
trait Foo[A <: Foo[A]] {
  def f: A
}

class Bar extends Foo[Bar] {
  def f: Bar = new Bar
}

class Baz extends Foo[Baz] {
  def f: Baz = new Baz
}
```

I don't know how your specific example should work, because I don't know how you would sum on that type.